# How to catch nil on "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier"

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I find often in my projects that I may need to initiate a UIViewController by Storyboard ID/Restoration ID; however, I often get the ID by querying a Dictionary containing the ID associated with a title, and it is possible some of the ID's are not actually valid/created yet resulting in a exception being raised. Is there a way to determine that the ID does not exist without a exception being raised? I attempted this with simple "if-then" logic but no success. Here what I got.

```
var VC: UIViewController? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(masterViewList["ExampleView"]!) as UIViewController?
        if VC == nil {
            //NOT FOUND
            alert.title = "Unable to Find UIViewController"
            alert.message = "The Selected View is unavailable!"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
        }
        else {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC!, animated: true)
        }
```

Apple's Documentation clearly states when "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" fails, it will raise an exception so I know why the above code does not work, I just don't know if there is a way around it or if I just I got to live with it raising exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation does say that the method will raise an exception, but the method signature:

```
open func instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController
```

says otherwise. Apparently what they mean is that UIKit will raise an exception that terminates the application.